# How to avoid illegal state exception?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, error-handling

Every time I get a "405 method not allowed" response from the server, I want to redirect the user to a given url.  However, I keep getting IllegalStateExceptions saying the response has already committed.  Is there any way I can redirect the user without getting this exception?

I have the following servlet:

```
public class MethodNotAllowedHandler extends HttpServlet {
      @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
                     throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

and the following entry in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MethodNotAllowedHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ex.MethodNotAllowedHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MethodNotAllowedHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MethodNotAllowedHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/MethodNotAllowedHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

Thanks

**Edit:** Meant to add the stack trace:

> 09:01:33,326 ERROR
>   [[MethodNotAllowedHandler]]
>   Servlet.service() for servlet
>   MethodNotAllowedHandler threw
>   exception
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:435)
>     at
>   com.ex.MethodNotAllowedHandler.doGet(MethodNotAllowedHandler.java:26)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:447)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, and I think I know why-- it seems this 405 exception is occurring more than once, so the 2nd time the handler catches it, the response is already committed.  This fixed my problem:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws    
         ServletException, IOException {
    if (!resp.isCommitted()) {
        resp.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
    } else {
        log.info("    Response was already committed!");
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will work, can't you directly give the URL in the location attribute?

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>http://www.google.com</location>
</error-page>
```

**EDIT:** Alright, I found that it won't work the above way. But the technique you have posted yourself worked for me. So what I suspect is that there are multiple redirects happening either through a filter or another JSP.

Comment: That won't work for me-- I tried that originally-- and the client gets the HTML content, but it would still come through with a 405 status code and show up as an error on the client's end.

Comment: Well, believe it or not, I tried what you have tried and it worked for me. I tried for 404 and my location had a /NotFound servlet.

Comment: I believe you.  Part of the problem I assume is the response is already committed before it's getting to this method.  I wonder if there's a difference in this between 404 and 405 errors.